# Is it okay to create many instances of firebase realtime database (>20) in one project

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need some advice. We have an android app with million+ daily active users. We use firebase realtime database. As firebase realtime db has 100K connection limit, we had created 10 db instances and distributed the load equally. (All databases has same data, and we update db2-db10 using firebase functions, we write to default db first)
Now we are getting more users and 10 instances aren't enough. We need to create more. We're planning to create another 10DBs, is it fine to do so?
It feels weird to have so many instances so I'm just being careful if it's safe to do so. As db instance once created can't be deleted either.

Comment: This sounds like a very specific use case. You should consider reaching out to Firebase support directly for direction on the best way to handle that many users/instances. They may also have input on an appropriate pricing program.

Comment: *firebaser here* Be sure to check your Firebase console for the number of *concurrently active* users on each shard, as DAU hardly ever translates 1:1 to concurrency. If you still need that many instances after that check, 20 is not an unreasonable number. If you experience any issues or grow further and want a double-check, I'd [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no documented limit to the number of databases (often referred to as shards) you can have within a project. Each database essentially functions as a completely separate instance, so there isn't any reason to have a limit at all. As long as you can spread your users over the shards, it can scale infinitely.

That said: Be sure to check your Firebase console for the number of *concurrently active* users on each shard, as DAU hardly ever translates 1:1 to concurrency. You might be able to get by with much fewer shards.

But if you really need that many instances after that check, 20 is not an unreasonable number. If you experience any issues or grow further and want a double-check, I'd [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help.

Comment: Thank you so much @Frank van Puffelen, the fact that each database instance function separately is relaxing. Currently, we have created 20 db instances. Actually we want to stop using the previous db instances, as some developers are misusing those databases' data for their apps, the database structured is exposed and we can't put any kind of authentication for our apps' old version to run properly. So we planned when most the users will have moved to the new dbs, we'll discontinue them.