# How to create new Firebase Realtime Database Instance using Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been using firebase for different kind of projects with firestore. But, I have not used real-time database due to low concurrent connection and some factors. Firestore also have some limitation such as 10000 per second per database. When I compare firestore with realtime database, It is possible to manage high traffic with many databases using real-time database. I red different articles and stack overflow questions and they had mentioned use cloud task and cloud scheduler to mange write failures in firestore. However, My questions are,

**Can I use cloud functions to create real-time databases?**

**How many real-time databases can be created per project?**
(*I am going to create a database per user, If there 1 Million Users = 1 Million real-time databases*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it okay to create many instances of firebase realtime database (>20) in one project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312508/is-it-okay-to-create-many-instances-of-firebase-realtime-database-20-in-one-p) From the answer:  "There is no documented limit to the number of databases (often referred to as shards) you can have within a project. Each database essentially functions as a completely separate instance, so there isn't any reason to have a limit at all."

Comment: That question do not mention about creating real-time databases via cloud function

Comment: I edited the title to clarify the question.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can accept & upvote it else feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: For your last questions, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55314601/209103

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Even Can we create one million real-time databases? That is a lot.  To be honest, I am student and I have not studied yet about databases and I don't have deep knowledge about this.  Do you think, creating a real-time database per user would be practical? and Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Firebase Realtime Database Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/database-management/rest) to create new instances of Realtime Database from a Cloud function. You need an access token with these scopes:

```js
[
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase'
]
```

Now the easiest way to do this is use [`googleapis`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) node module in you cloud function along with your service account.

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis');

exports.createDbInstance = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      keyFile: __dirname + '/serviceAccountKey.json',
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
  });

  const accessToken = await auth.getAccessToken()
  const response = await google.firebasedatabase("v1beta")
          .projects
          .locations
          .instances
          .create({ 
            databaseId: "new-db-id", 
            parent: "projects/[PROJECT-ID]/locations/[LOCATION]",
            access_token: accessToken 
          })
  console.log(response)
  return {data: "New Database Created"}
});
```

You can download a Service Account JSON file from here: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk

This shouldn't ideally be a callable function with no authentication. Make sure you implement your own logic so only authorized people can call this function.

`[PROJECT-ID]` is the ID of project in which you want to create the database.

`[LOCATION]` is the location you want to create the database in. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#rtdb-locations) is a list of available locations.

Comment: @Dharmaraja, Let me try and I will let you know, Thank you.

Comment: @IsuruBandara sure. You can just create a new node project and paste the code and run it as a short cut ;)

Comment: @Dharmaraja Can we update the real-time database rules along with this function?

Comment: @IsuruBandara Yes, you can update  security rules using the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/app-management)

Comment: Thank you mate. One last question. Do you think real-time database per user will be practical? Imaging If we have 1 million users mean 1 million databases, and each database can be have 200k Simultaneous connections.

Comment: @IsuruBandara it depends on what you are trying to offer tbh. I'm not sure what scale are we talking about and so. Do you really need 1 database for each user? Like how much data are they going to store anyways?

Comment: Firebase only charge as we go, Therefore, It won't be a problem and My app like a retail shop, So Each shop owner can have a database to store items.

Comment: @IsuruBandara tbh if you have concerns about performance issues with creating that many database then I'd recommend contacting Firebase support as I've never created more than 4-5 databases per project. If I was creating such application then I'd just use single DB and create 1 node for each shop.  Unless you need realtime listeners for more than 200K users.